# Why is "how to ask a question" not in the top three?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I go to the help center, and I find, in order, that number 11 is "how to ask a good question" and there is a whole lot of admin stuff on top of that.
We get a lot of closed questions.
We get a lot of questions now well asked. (as do other SE's)

I would think that in the help, helping someone with how to ask a question, which is an art on SE sites, would be in the top 3.

Can we get this bumped?

What topics can I ask about here?

What types of questions should I avoid asking?

What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"?

Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?

Why do I see a message that my question does not meet quality standards?

What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?

Why and how are some questions deleted?

Why are some questions marked as duplicate?

What should I do if no one answers my question?

How do I ask a good question?

Why is the system asking me to wait a day or more before asking another question?

How to Ask Questions in Private Beta

What should I do when someone answers my question?

What are tags, and how should I use them?

Comment: I could be wrong, but it doesn't look like moderators have control over the order of topics.  We could probably ask a CM to modify it for us, but we may have an even better tool available – the area between the search box and the "Find out more about..." section.  For a simple example, see [Latin.SE's help page](https://latin.stackexchange.com/help).  For more elaborate guidance, see [Hardware Recs](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help) or even [French](https://french.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: @nat Yeah, I certainly wouldn't be opposed to putting things like "What is a 'Truth Question' and why can't I ask it here?", etc... in the Help Center.

Comment: @PeterTurner As far as I am concerned, the top three are "how do I ask a question, what topics, and what should I do when someone answers followed by what should I do if no one answers?  New people will be best helped with those.  Should I answer this myself?

Comment: @korvin, we dont control the order, but we can stick make a post-above-the-post that is completley unique.  If you want to give a try at making that I don't see why we shouldnt go ahead and use it if people like it